# How to handle require() in Angular 2 spec file

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I have a Angular 2 service that looks similar to below. It functions correctly, however when running unit tests (even without any expects) it fails with the following TypeError. My service is written in TypeScript and has the correct imports. However, there is 1 node module that is written in JavaScript (as a module.export =....) so I can't import it and instead 'require' it. I am wondering how I can mock this or inject it correctly so it doesn't fail in the unit tests. It works fine in practice, just the test cases fail.

Angular 2 Servive:

```
let x = require('some-file')

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {
    x(foo)
  }
}
```

Angular 2 Test File:

```
describe('Service: MyService', () => {

  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [MyService]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([NativeBridgeService], s => {   
    service = s;
  }));

});
```

TypeError: x is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You have to intstall typings for that lib. Then you can use the lib with import not require. Try

```
npm install @types/<here goes your lib name>
```

If they don't exists write them yourself.

Comment: It is a custom js library that I wrote. Do I just need to add some TypeScript type definition files? eg. d.ts ?

Comment: yeap, if you are the author you can also place d.ts file in the lib

Comment: Quick question though, does the d.ts file look like:


    export * from 'my-module'

Comment: ;), no I don't think so. The easiest way would be checking a lib that has typings and follow the convention

Comment: Can you give me an example library to look at? Every one I am has the export * from 'some module'

Comment: try: 
npm i jQuery
npm i @types/jQuery
in node_modules/@types/jquery there should be d.ts file